# Null pointer exception for TextView?

Tags: java, android, textview

So i'm trying to display a `TextView` whenever a user clicks an item on a `ListView`. However, when i click a list item, i get this error...

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference`.

What causes this to occur in regards to "TextViews" specifically and are there any possible solutions to solving it? Thanks.

### Update

Here's how i set the TextViews..

**Activity**

```
@Override
public void onTextFooterListener(String String1, String String2) {

    tab1.setLabels(String1, String2);

}
```

**Tab1Fragment**

```
public void setLabels(String mString1, String mString2) {

    title1 = mString1;
    title2= mString2;

    title1Footer.setText(title1);
    title2Footer.setText(title2);
    updateTimerLabel();
}
```

**TextViews**

```
title1Footer= (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.title1_footer);
title2Footer= (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.title2_footer);
```

`tab1` is declared as `public Tab1Fragment tab1 = new Tab1Fragment();`

If i comment out the `onTextFooterListener`, the code seems to work just fine...

Comment: you have not initialized the textView......

Comment: Please post the relevant code.

Comment: just do like this TextView.setText(""+yourtext) and check if it returns null

Comment: just debug it and see what you are passing on the textview

Comment: @NongthonbamTonthoi...I think you can not say it is duplicate one...ya..i know...Exception is same but the situation is different...

Comment: I've updated the post

Comment: you are setting string to textview using textview.setText(YOUR STRING)...But string is null.. So that NullPointerException is occurring. Check your String Data and also check if your textview is initialized or not. Hope it will help :)

Comment: If you comment out the onTextFooterListener means you are not calling the function setLables...Try to debug and check what values you are getting in setLabels method

Comment: Post your code where you declare 'tab1'

Comment: Actually the error is saying that your `TextView` is null, not the string. It means that you don't initialize the `TextView` or initialize it in a wrong way, please paste the code where you initialize the `TextView`

Comment: Check the post. Thanks.